# Check if clipboard is image

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word, clipboard, copy-paste

I am trying to copy a `.PDF` into Word and Excel (showing code just for Word here, almost same for Excel). To do this I use [IrfranView](https://www.irfanview.com/) to convert the `.PDF` to an image, but it only works sometimes, no idea why? I think I need to wait some time before pasting it.

Is there  a way I can check if the clipboard contains an image and keep looping until it does or timer is more than lets say 1.5s?

```
'Add pdf of drawing to word file
If zFile <> "" Then
    Dim oData As New MSForms.DataObject
    oData.SetText Text:="Empty" 'Clear
    oData.PutInClipboard 'take in the clipboard to empty it
    Shell "C:\Program Files (x86)\IrfanView\i_view32.exe " & zFile _
        & "/clipcopy /convert=" & Environ("AppData") _
        & "\IrfanView\ConverTemp.jpg /jpgq=100"
    Sleep (1000)
    copyImg = Not oData.GetFormat(1)
    If copyImg Then
        Documents(docLogSkjema).Activate
        Selection.EndKey Unit:=wdStory
        Selection.InsertBreak Type:=wdSectionBreakNextPage
        With Selection.PageSetup
            .Orientation = wdOrientLandscape
            .PageWidth = CentimetersToPoints(42)
            .PageHeight = CentimetersToPoints(29.7)
        End With
        With Selection.Sections(1).Headers(wdHeaderFooterPrimary)
            .LinkToPrevious = False
            .Range.Delete
            .LinkToPrevious = False
            .Range.Delete
        End With
        Selection.Paste
    End If
End If
```

Answer (score 4):

Here is the code to check whether there is a picture on the clipboard, use this code in a separate module:

```
#If Win64 Then
  Private Declare PtrSafe Function IsClipboardFormatAvailable Lib "user32" _
      (ByVal wFormat As Long) As Long
#Else
  Private Declare Function IsClipboardFormatAvailable Lib "user32" _
      (ByVal wFormat As Long) As Long
#End If

Function Is_Pic_in_Clipboard() As Boolean
  If IsClipboardFormatAvailable(2)<>0 Or IsClipboardFormatAvailable(14)<>0 Then _
      Is_Pic_in_Clipboard = True '2=BMP, 14=JPEG
End Function
```

Then, to determine whether there is a picture, use `If Is_Pic_in_Clipboard Then ...`

---

### More Info:

- **MS Docs** : [`IsClipboardFormatAvailable` function](https://learn.microsoft.com/windows/desktop/api/winuser/nf-winuser-isclipboardformatavailable)
- [**Standard Clipboard Formats**](https://learn.microsoft.com/windows/desktop/dataxchg/standard-clipboard-formats)

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can check if it contains *any* image but you can check if it no longer contains text. How about something like this:

```
oData.SetText "Empty"                         ' create dummy string as object
oData.PutInClipboard                          ' load dummy string to clipboard
Do Until x = 15 Or oData.GetFormat(1) = False ' loop until counter hits 15 or dummy text missing
    x = x + 1                                 ' increment counter
    Sleep (100)                               ' wait
    oData.GetFromClipboard                    ' reload from clipboard
Loop                                          ' end of loop
```

Change the `Until x=15` to something more appropriate as needed. Then do your final check to decide to paste or not.